# Getting same error with gRPC over and over "--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: php, laravel, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm following Quick start on this link: https://grpc.io/docs/languages/php/quickstart/

I'm doing this steps like 3 or 4 times again and again and I'm always stuck at one same point.

When I need to run :

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=examples/protos \
--php_out=examples/php \
--grpc_out=examples/php \
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=bins/opt/grpc_php_plugin \
./examples/protos/helloworld.proto
```

I'm getting error:

```
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I can run something like this and it will make connection with server ( I'm getting expected log on gRPC server):

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=examples/protos \
--php_out=examples/php \
./examples/protos/helloworld.proto
```

I have installed protoc and it is in PATH, I can run protoc --version. I have this in comoser.json

```
"require": {
  "grpc/grpc": "^v1.39.0",
  "google/protobuf": "^v3.12.2"
},
```

PHP versions I tried on is: 7.4, 8.0, 8.1, 8.2. I'm on Windows 10.

Can anyone help me with this or just try to give me some advice what to look and check, I am new to gRPC.

Thnak you all!!

Comment: I'm familiar with gRPC but not using PHP. The instructions on grpc.io and the repo appear to contradict. In the repo's `README` for [`grpc-protoc-plugin`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.60.0/src/php/README.md#grpc_php_plugin-protoc-plugin) it says that the plugin can be found in `cmake/build/grpc_php_plugin` but the gRPC site has `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=bins/opt/grpc_php_plugin` and thus `bins/opt`. Which directory contains `grpc_php_plugin`?

Answer (score 0):

I followed these [instructions](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.60.0/src/php/README.md#grpc_php_plugin-protoc-plugin) and used [`health.proto`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/health/v1/health.proto) as an example.
Before:

```bash
tree ${HOME}/examples
```

```
~/examples
└── health.proto
```

And:

```bash
WORK="${HOME}/grpc/cmake/build"

${WORK}/third_party/protobuf/protoc \
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=${WORK}/grpc_php_plugin \
--proto_path=${HOME}/examples \
--php_out=${HOME}/examples \
--grpc_out=${HOME}/examples \
${HOME}/examples/health.proto
```

> **NOTE**
>
> - `WORK` and `HOME` used for clarity.
> - Once a `--proto_path` is defined (i.e. `${HOME}/examples`), it must be repeated for protobuf sources that are relative to it (i.e. `${HOME}/examples/health.proto`)
>   After:

```bash
tree ${HOME}/examples
```

```
~/examples
├── GPBMetadata
│   └── Health.php
├── Grpc
│   └── Health
│       └── V1
│           ├── HealthCheckRequest.php
│           ├── HealthCheckResponse
│           │   └── ServingStatus.php
│           ├── HealthCheckResponse.php
│           └── HealthClient.php
└── health.proto
```